# How to access shadowRoot for css styling (Polymer1.0)

Tags: polymer

In Polymer0.5 I could do something like:

```
domReady: function(){
    print(this.shadowRoot);
}
```

Which would print out the html in the shadowRoot.

---

When I do the same thing in Polymer1.0:

```
ready: function(){
    print(this.shadowRoot);
}
```

the output is `null`.

---

More specifically, I used to access an elements css attributes by doing:

```
$(this.shadowRoot).find('.some-class').css('height', amount + 'px');
```

But am struggling to find out how to do this in Polymer1.0, since the shadowRoot is null.

Comment: AFAIK, they replaced the shadow dom with the 'shady dom'. I haven't used it yet, but according to [the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/articles/shadydom.html) you can access the shady dom as `var arrayOfNodes = Polymer.dom(x-element).children;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [jdepypere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1319187/jdepypere) for the hint.  It turns out that all of the style attributes are in the style property of the node property.

So to adjust the height:

```
Polymer.dom(this.$.scrollArea).node.style.height = '100px';
```

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may also want to look at Polymer's built in `transform` and `translate3d` utility functions: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/utility-functions.html and https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/